# Installed Nonpareil-cm from the snap store but cannot find it to run it

Tags: software-installation, snap

I installed Nonpareil (a special calculator emulator) from the Snap store, but can not find the program to run it.  (Using Ubuntu 20.04.3)

These directories now exist : 
/snap/nonpareil-cm 
/var/snap/nonpareil-cm 
but I don't know what to find there that might be used to start the program.  
I tried `snap run nonpareil-cm` but received the error message

```
error : cannot find app "nonpareil-cm" in "nonpareil-cm"
```

Even rebooted -- made no difference.  
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its [snapcraft.yml](https://github.com/cmatsuoka/nonpareil-snap/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml) file it provide the following executables:

- `nonpareil-cm.21`
- `nonpareil-cm.25`
- `nonpareil-cm.32e`
- `nonpareil-cm.33c`
- `nonpareil-cm.34c`
- `nonpareil-cm.35`
- `nonpareil-cm.37e`
- `nonpareil-cm.38c`
- `nonpareil-cm.38e`
- `nonpareil-cm.41cv`
- `nonpareil-cm.41cx`
- `nonpareil-cm.45`
- `nonpareil-cm.55`
- `nonpareil-cm.80`
- `nonpareil-cm.modutil`
- `nonpareil-cm.nonpareil`
- `nonpareil-cm.uasm`

So you have to launch the main executable - `nonpareil-cm.nonpareil` and select needed calculator or run single calculator of needed model by command like `nonpareil-cm.41cv`.

---

Note: issue about adding desktop-files to Snap is [filed to GitHub](https://github.com/cmatsuoka/nonpareil-snap/issues/1).

Comment: Thank you, N0rbert.  That works exactly as you describe and solves my problem.  Thanks, too, for filing the issue about desktop-files at GitHub.  "Super", as my son would say.  Thanks again for your help.